# Integrating User profile system with comment system with Python Django

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite, web

I have created a Comment system with django, previously anyone could comment regardless of account status, however i have started to integrate my user system to ensure that people commenting have an account. I have thought of many ways to carry this out however I am not sure how to replace the user-inputted 'name' field with the already set 'username'. I have tried using this code so far.

The problem occurs when I submit the comment, as I believe there is no link between user and author at all, incorporating this link is where I am struggling though.

models.py (The comment model)

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_comments')
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment
```

views.py (How the comment is saved to the post)

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post, status="published", publish__year=year, publish__month=month, publish__day=day)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    post_tag_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
    similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tag_ids).exclude(id=post.id)
    similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags')).order_by('-same_tags', '-publish')[:3]

    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {"post": post, "comments":comments, "new_comment":new_comment, "comment_form": comment_form, 'similar_posts': similar_posts})
```

forms.py (The form for actually commenting)

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

details.html (Displaying the comment form, displaying comments)

```
<div class="commentcontainer">
        <h2 class="headingcomment">Comments</h2>
        {% for comment in comments %}
        <div class="comment">
            <p class="info">
                {{ comment.author }}
                {{ comment.created }}
            </p>
            {{ comment.body|linebreaks }}
        </div>
        {% empty %}
        <p class="nocomments">There are no comments on this post</p>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if new_comment %}
        <h2>Your comment has been added</h2>
        {% else %}
        <form method="POST">
            <label class="commentlabel" for="comment_form.body.id_for_label">Comment:</label>
            {{ comment_form.body }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>
                <input class="commentsubmit" type="submit" value="Comment" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

When I type into the comment TextArea and click the submit button though an error is returned

'django.db.utils.IntegrityError
'django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_comment.author_id'

I am aware of what NOT NULL means and how the constraint failed, however I am unsure as to where I should be placing author_id or where it even originates from as its not used anywhere?

Can anyone tell me whereabouts in all of the code above I would incorporate the User and system and the code I would have to use to do this at all? I am not too sure if I am on the right lines with the current code.

Originally the comment form had a name and email input, however by incorporating the User system with the comments I was hoping author_id could be linked to the UserID behind the scenes using python. For example instead of entering 'Andrew Crossan' the system would link the currently logged in account username, 'AndrewCrossan' to the comment as the author.

I have tried the following:

```
new_comment.author = User.get_username()
```

,

```
new_comment.author = User.username
```

,

```
new_comment.author = request.user.username
```

,

```
user_name = User.username
new_comment.author = user_name
```

If any clarification, extra code or questions are necessary I will happily provide.

Comment: i think is this line {{ comment_form.body }}, also the fact that your form only contians body, so there is no way of knowing the author by foreign key,

Comment: @tahamaatof I think the {{ comment_form.body}} is okay, but I agree with you on not knowing the author, could you possibly give me a hand on how to incorporate author by foreign key, or link me to some resources?

Comment: add new_comment.author = request.user before new_comment.save(),

Comment: request.user doesn't work, it returns 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'username'. I tried User.username aswell and it returned "Comment.author" must be a "User" instance.